# Copy DataGridView content to a multiple TextBoxes

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I have a DataGridView with 3 columns, and I want that when I click a cell, the content from it will be copied to 2 different textboxes and 1 combobox. So far, the only thing I've come into is something like this:

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.CopyTo = txtCveMun.Text;
    }
```

The above doesn't work at all, it's just something I came into messing around with the libraries.
So, what should I do? Thanks!

If anyone cares, this is the method I fill up my DataGridView:

```
private void CargaDataGridView()
    {
        conexion.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT m.cvemunicipio, m.nombre AS NombreA, e.nombre AS NombreB FROM tbMunicipios m INNER JOIN tbEstados e ON m.CveEstado = e.CVeEstado";
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rd.GetValue(0), rd.GetValue(1), rd.GetValue(2));
            }
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

The complete answer for this is

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCveMun.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString();
        txtNomMun.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString();
        cbEstado.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Column3"].FormattedValue.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to set DatagridView Selection mode to `FullRowSelect` then you can get the value of the column by :

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ColummName"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Obama, but where do I "set DatagridView Selection mode to FullRowSelect"?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't understand where to do what

Comment: Just Select the DatagridView and go to the property panel and search for Selection mode :)

Comment: Yeah, I *just* figured that out :D

Comment: But where do I put "dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ColummName"].Value.ToString();" ?

Comment: So for example in the doubleClick event of the datagridView you set 
txtCveMun.Text=dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["CveMun"].Value.ToString(); and finally when you doubleClick on the row on runtime you will get the value in the text that's it :)

Comment: The only problem I have it's with my combobox :(, it doesn't copy the text.

Comment: Have you set comboBox1.text="..." ? or what?

Comment: No, i haven't done that. I guess the problem is that my combobox and my datagridview display the "name" column, but what I really need to use is "id"... You know, sql relations

Comment: I messed around a little bit, and the best I can do is cbEstado.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Column3"].Displayed.ToString();, but it show "true" in the combobox, instead of the name of the state.

Comment: Ah ok so try :
comboBox1.DisplayMember="ColumnName";
comboBox1.ValueMember="ID";
comboBox1.Datasource=....
just search about that and you'll find the solution

Comment: I get your point. I'll get back to you as soon as I find a valid answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy content from [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) to your controls e.g textbox you can use rows and cells collection to get values of cells in the [CellContentClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx) event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    txtCveMun.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

If you want to get the values of cell from current row being click then you can use column names.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    txtCveMun.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["gridViewColumnName1"].Value.ToString();
    txtSomeControl.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["gridViewColumnName2"].Value.ToString();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this, and I'll get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks for your input! My answer is a tidbit different.